# Python: replace list items and produce all possible permutations

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, list

I am trying to implement morse decode for partial morse code.Say for example the representation of word TEST in morse code is ['-','.','...','-'] however if the first character of every morse code string is missing and represented by x then partial morse code for TEST will become ['x','x','x..','x'].Thus in order to decode this partial message, we will have to replace x with either. or - for every occurrence of x in above partial morse code.With 'x' unknown the permutations of TEST word on decoding would be ETST,EEDT,ETSE etc.I have implemented the morse partial decode function as below:

```
def morsePartialDecode(inputStringList):
    with open('words.txt','a') as wordfile:
        dictionaryFileLoc = './dictionary.txt'
        message_received = inputStringList
        message_received = ' '.join(inputStringList)
        for i in range(len(message_received)):
            x = 'x'
            y = '.'
        message = message_received.replace(x, y)
        message1 = message.split(",")
        message_converted = morseDecode(message1)
        print message_converted
        print >> wordfile, (message_converted)
        for i in range(len(message_received)):
            x = 'x'
            y = '-'
        message = message_received.replace(x, y)
        message2 = message.split(",")
        message_converted = morseDecode(message2)
        print >> wordfile, (message_converted)
        elements = []
    wordfile.closed
    return message_converted

def partialMorseCodeTest():
    test = ['x', 'x', 'x..', 'x']
    print morsePartialDecode(test)  

partialMorseCodeTest()

Output:
EESE
TTDT
```

I need all the combinations of ['x','x','x..','x'] with x replaced by . or -.And my morseDecode() will convert each combination to respective words like EESE, TTDT etc[morsedecode](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MDia5hroblMkEKDkkz7YXeP6S7z8vpry))What to do.Thanks in advance!

Comment: so, if I understand you correctly, you need all the combinations of `['x','x','x..','x']` with `x` replaced by `.` or `-`? And your `morseDecode()` will convert each combination to respective words like EESE, TTDT etc?

Comment: Yes you are correct!

Comment: please update your question accordingly!

Comment: Is there a limit of single replacement per letter in partial code or do you need to handle e.g.: `['-', 'x.x', 'x']` as well?

Answer (score 1):

Great case for itertools

Example using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

def replace_x_with_all_combinations(morse):
    # only works with 1 and 1 only 'x' in each element
    all_perm = list()
    for v in morse:
        if 'x' in v:
            # create a list of permutations per element of the morse list
            # and append them to the all_perm list
            all_perm.append([v.replace('x','.'), v.replace('x','-')])
        else:
            # if no x found, then append the original element
            all_perm.append([v])
    # all_perm = [['.', '-'], ['.', '-'], ['...', '-..'], ['.', '-']]
    # the list all_perm needs to be unpacked before passing
    # to the product() generator, hence the *
    return list(product(*all_perm))

partial = ['x','x','x..','x']
result = replace_x_with_all_combinations(partial)
for e in result:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
('.', '.', '...', '.')
('.', '.', '...', '-')
('.', '.', '-..', '.')
('.', '.', '-..', '-')
('.', '-', '...', '.')
('.', '-', '...', '-')
('.', '-', '-..', '.')
('.', '-', '-..', '-')
('-', '.', '...', '.')
('-', '.', '...', '-')
('-', '.', '-..', '.')
('-', '.', '-..', '-')
('-', '-', '...', '.')
('-', '-', '...', '-')
('-', '-', '-..', '.')
('-', '-', '-..', '-')
```

[EDIT]
Although I put the restriction in the above code myself, the "works only for 1 x in the morse character" bugged me, so the following example will take more than one digit missing from a morse character, more than one 'x'

```
from itertools import product


def replace_x_in_morse_charcter(morse_character):
    all_perm = [['.','-'] if c == 'x' else [c] for c in morse_character]
    p = list(product(*all_perm))
    return [''.join([v for v in e]) for e in p]


def replace_x_in_morse_word(morse):
    all_perm = [replace_x_in_morse_charcter(c) for c in morse]
    return list(product(*all_perm))


partial = ['x','x','x..','xx']
result = replace_x_in_morse_word(partial)
for e in result:
    print(e)
```

[EDIT] for fun a one liner:

```
morse_word = ['x','x','x..','xx']
result = list(product(*[[''.join([v for v in e]) for e in list(product(*[['.','-'] if c == 'x' else [c] for c in cm]))] for cm in morse_word]))
```

Comment: Any chance you can explain what this does?     all_perm = [['.','-'] if c == 'x' else [c] for c in morse_character]

Comment: @Alligator : if the morse character (containing dots and dashes and x's) has an x, it will return a dot and a dash in place of the x, else it will return the original dot or dash. So it will return all permutations of the possible morse character with dots and dashes replacing x's. I hope that answers your question.